# How to change product price during or after import csv file in magento?

Tags: php, csv, magento

I have 1000 Jewelry products. When I upload CSV file using Magento import functionality, so at that time products price will be changed automatically with my custom calculation formula.

Ex: csv product price = 100 but after import product price will be 150.

Please help me how can I implement this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution for above problem.
I am using hooking below is my code.

```
<adminhtml>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_import_finish_before>
                <observers>
                    <test_module1_catalog_product_import_after>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>gold_pricechange/observer</class>
                        <method>afterImportProductData</method>
                    </test_module1_catalog_product_import_after>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_import_finish_before>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>

public function afterImportProductData(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {       
        $adapter = $observer->getEvent()->getAdapter();
        $affectedEntityIds = $adapter->getAffectedEntityIds();

        for($i=0;$i<count($affectedEntityIds);$i++)
        {
            $product_id = $affectedEntityIds[$i];
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
            $product->setPrice($product->getPrice() * 1.2); //1.2 will come from my calculation function

            $product->save();
            $product->clearInstance();
        }       
    }
```

Sorry if my question was wrong.

Thank you for great help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this extension [price import](http://extensions.streammarket.co.uk/bulk-product-price-group-price-import-export.html)

Comment: Thank you Faizabeg for help but I need to programmatically.